# Angular 2 post method to pass two parameter

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to post data on an action which has two parameter in it ho could I achieve. I am using angular 2 in asp.net mvc 5 application.

```
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl, UserLogin _user)
{

    return RedirectToAction("ExternalSignIn", new { returnUrl = returnUrl, userEmail = _user.Email });

 }
```

Comment: `this.http.post('/Account/Login', JSON.stringify([this.returnUrl, this.email])).subscribe();`

Answer (score 5):

Firstly make sure you are importing the following:

```
import { Http, Headers } from 'angular2/http';
```

Then this for your service call

```
let url = 'base api url/Account/Login';
let data = {
    "returnUrl": this.returnUrl,
    "email": this.email
};   
let body = JSON.stringify(data )
let head = new Headers({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
});

this.http.post(url, body , {headers : head})
    .map(res =>  res.json())
    .subscribe((data:any) => {
      //subscribe actions
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
floor: Floor = { id: 0, name: "", floorNumber: 0, addressNumber: "", floorTypeid: 0 };

floorUnit: FloorUnit = { id: 0, floorID: 0, unitID: 0, addressNumber: '',unitCost: 0, standardPrice: 0, taxTermid: 0, imageUrl: '', planUrl: '', isAvailable: true, isTemperoryBooking: false, isNotReleased: false };

const floorUnitAddURL = "api/floorunit/AddFloorUnit";

// you can pass two class objects in same post method by array as follows 
    AddFloorUnit() {
        if (this.validationService.Validate(this.floorUnitForm, this.floorUnitFormErrors, this.floorUnitValidationMessages))
 {

            this.apiService.post(floorUnitAddURL, [this.floorUnit, this.floor], true).subscribe(
                res => {
                    var data: any = res;
                    if (data && data.status.success) {
                        this.notificationService.NotifyError("Success", data.status.displayMessage, "success");
                        //this.ResetPropertyForm();
                    }
                    else
                        this.notificationService.NotifyError("Error", data.status.displayMessage, "warning");
                },
                err => {
                    this.notificationService.NotifyError("Error", "Error Occured.", "warning");
                });
        }
    };
```

And in  Web API method two separate parameters with

```
[HttpPost("AddFloorUnit")]
public JsonResult Post([FromBody]FloorUnitDTO floorUnit , [FromBody]FloorDTO floor)
        {
            try
            {
                Floor updateFloor = Mapper.Map<Floor>(floor);
                Proxy<Floor>.SetBaseEntityProperties(Request, updateFloor, true);
                _floorService.UpdateFloor(updateFloor);


                FloorUnit newfloorUnit = Mapper.Map<FloorUnit>(floorUnit);
                Proxy<FloorUnit>.SetBaseEntityProperties(Request, newfloorUnit);
                _floorUnitService.AddFloorUnit(newfloorUnit);
                return Json(ErrorHandle<FloorUnit>.GetSuccessMessage(null));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log4netLogger<FloorUnit>.Error(Constants.ExceptionPolicy.BusinessLogic, ex);
                return Json(ErrorHandle<FloorUnit>.GetInsertErrorMessage(ErrorCodes.FloorUnitInsertError, typeof(FloorUnit).Name));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue before, and I resolved by making modifications on back-end code.

Instead to have 2 parameters in the function API I created a new model with the parameters as properties.

Before:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult ChangingStatusAS(int id, int action)
 {
   ...
 }
```

After:

```
 public class PostChangingStatusAS
 {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int action { get; set; }            
 }
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult ChangingStatusAS(PostChangingStatusAS param)
 {
    ...
 }
```

Service call by using Angular:

```
let data = {
  id: 25,
  action: 25
};   
let body = JSON.stringify(data)
let head = new Headers({
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
});

this._http.post(url,body , {headers : head})
.map(res =>  res.json())
.subscribe((data:any) => {
  //subscribe actions
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to crate a class to pass multiple params to a post, it is in the definition of the post method, if you want to pass standalone parameters.

Angular post only accept object in the body ex.

```
this._http.post(url, {moo:"foo",goo:"loo"}).....
```